# Script to pull an image from a Website

Tags: php, javascript, html, scripting

I have a website on which I want to post the current [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com) comic. xkcd provides a link for embedding, but each link has a unique name for each comic. For example, http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/hotels.png is today's comic.

Is there any way to write a simple script to grab the latest comic from their website? Currently I'm just manually updating the URL on my site which is painful.

Comment: You can't really do this with javascript all that easily. You need some way to pull the html down from the site and parse it for the Image URL text.

Comment: @IanNorton [that's just not true, mate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628375/script-to-pull-image-from-website/7628404#7628404)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randall provides [RSS](http://www.xkcd.com/rss.xml) and [Atom](http://www.xkcd.com/atom.xml) feeds for recent XKCDs. Parse one of those to get the latest comics.

Comment: Running into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324697/can-i-make-an-xmlhttprequest-to-another-domain) problem.

Comment: Fetch (and, if you so wish, parse) the feed on the server, not in the browser. Or, use [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) or the [Google Feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/)

Comment: Ah! Turned out to be much easier using PHP. Used a variant of a simple script I found [here](http://www.softarea51.com/tutorials/parse_rss_with_php.html). Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the problem for a moment. Where is the name of the current comic image shown? It's shown on the xkcd home page. You could write a script to retrieve the *home page*, search through the HTML for the current image link, and use that.

Comment: As a hint: It's the first `img` within the `div` which has the class `s`.

Comment: Totally unnecessary when there are perfectly good data feeds available.

Comment: @MattBall: While that's true, it's worthwhile for somebody who's *obviously* learning this stuff to understand how these things connect together.

Comment: Also, the question's title was quite generic. Not all websites provide feeds.